# Figcaption transition bug (Mozilla, Edge, IE)

Tags: html, css

I have some images, and on the `:hover` effect the `figcaption` should `translateY`, on chrome it works perfectly, but on the other browsers it shows the `figcaption` by default how you see below. Where I'm wrong? My website is on air in case of you want to see it by yourself: https://tiagosilveiraa.github.io

Bug on the other browsers:

[image]

Right Chrome:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
       <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
         <figure>
           <img src="img/hidrau.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras Hidraulicas" class="img-responsive">
           <figcaption>
           <a href="http://hidrauriomangueiras.com.br" target="_blank"><button >Visitar</button></a>
           <a href="https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/hidraurio" target="_blank"><button >Github</button></a>
           </figcaption>
         </figure>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio figure{
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#portfolio img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

#portfolio figure figcaption{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: #292929;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#portfolio figure:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-90px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-90px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-90px);
}
#portfolio figure:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Comment: why are you using `display: table` on `#portfolio figure`? It works if you remove that.

Comment: if I use other display the figcaption on't fit with the image :/

Comment: Seems to work for me if you just remove `display: table`. What do you mean the figcaption won't fit with the image? Try changing it to `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`

Comment: I works now, tank you :)

Comment: @michaelcoker, I just found that on ie, there's a new bug, the images are being Stretched I tried other flex directions and it does not work: / Print: http://prntscr.com/fdezbc